# Editing a svg (lxml) file whith beautifulsoup and regular expression

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup, lxml

I'm trying to make a script that modifies an .svg file (XML format). I'm trying to change the background color of one or more objects such as an array.

For the moment I think I've passed the first part of my code but I can't see how to register my color change.

Here's my code:

```
From bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

svg = open('draw.svg').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(svg ,'lxml')

paths = soup.find_all('path')

     for path in paths:
       if path.attrs['id']==('5'):
         print(path.attrs['style'])
         Str = re.sub( r'fill:#[0-9a-fA-F]{6}',
                       r'fil:#FFFFFF' ,
                       path.attrs['style'])
        path.attrs['style'] = Str
        print(Str)

    print(path.attrs['style'])
svg = open ('draw.svg' ,"w")
svg.write(paths)
svg.close()
```

what I want to modify is found in a path tag that contains 4 different attributes ( id , style ...)
For the moment I arrive in hard to identify my id then style, then I put a regular expression I try to change the value, but it does not change anything to the original file. I think I'm missing something, can you help me by advising me how to do ?

I can't see how I can read/write the file at the same time.

Comment: Can you post the xml from the actual `draw.svg`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to edit a path with the `id='5'`. Then you want to change it's `style` attribute containing `fill` to be `FFFFFF`. Then write it to a file. You can do this by:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

# Opening files using the with statement is generally recommended
# because it ensures that open file descriptors are
# closed automatically after program execution leaves the context
# of the with statement
with open('draw.svg') as file:
    svg = file.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(svg, 'lxml')

svg_tag = soup.find('svg')
path = svg_tag.find('path', {'id': '5'})
# There can be spaces between the fill and : and hex
# then either 1 or 2 groups of 3 alphanumeric characters.
# It can be multiline
path['style'] = re.sub(
    r'fill\s*:\s*#([a-fA-F0-9]{3}){1,2}',
    r'fill:#FFFFFF',
    path['style'],
    re.M
)

# print(soup)

# Open the file again using the with statement and write the svg tag contents.
with open('draw.svg', 'w') as file:
    file.write(str(svg_tag))
```

Input (draw.svg):

```
<svg width="450" height="450">
   <path id="5" d="M100,100 L150,100 L150,150  Z"
      style="stroke: #0000cc;
             stroke-width: 2px;
             fill  : #ccccff;"/>
</svg>
```

Output (draw.svg):

```
<svg height="450" width="450">
<path d="M100,100 L150,100 L150,150  Z" id="5" style="stroke: #0000cc;
             stroke-width: 2px;
             fill:#FFFFFF;"></path>
</svg>
```